# Como fazer com que uma busca a um banco de dados seja apresentado em tabela?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Há alguns dias estou tentando fazer com que a minha busca no BD, seja apresentada interiormente a uma tabela margeada. No entanto, embora o server nao retorne erro algum, nenhum resultado é mostrado. Já fiz várias alteraçoes na sintax com relaçao ao posicionamento das tags tables, colocando-a internamente ao WHILE porém até agora nao obtive sucesso algum. Segue abaixo o último modo que tentei:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Extraindo dados do BD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","DB1","XXXX") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("database1") or die(mysql_error());
        $selecaodedados= "SELECT * FROM meubancodedados";
        echo "<table style="1px">";
            echo    "<thead>    <tr> <th colspan='6'>Lista 1 </th></tr>"    
                ."</tread>";
            echo    "<tr>"
                ."<th> A dado </th> <th> B dado </th> <th> C dado </th>"
                ." <th>D dado </th> <th> E dado </th> <th> F total </th>"
                ."</tr>";
            echo    "</thead>";
            echo    " <tbody>";
        while($linha= mysql_fetch_array($selecaodedados)){
            echo "<tr>"
                ."<td>".$linha['A']. "</td><td> ". $linha['B']"
                . " </td><td> ".$linha['C']. "</td><td>  ". $linha['D']"
                . "</td><td>  ". $linha['E']."</td><td>  ".$linha['F']. "</td><br/>"
                ."</tr>";
            }
            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";            
        mysql_close();
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá. Desde já eu não recomendo mais utilizar MySql, já que o mesmo é obsoleto e está descontinuado. E também foi removido na versão 7.0.0 do PHP.

Mas, como a pergunta foi feita sobre MySQL, vamos respondê-la!
No seu código faltou você dar query

O correto seria:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Extraindo dados do BD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","USUARIO","SENHA") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("DATABASE") or die(mysql_error());
        $selecaodedados= "SELECT * FROM TABELA";
        $executar = mysql_query("$selecaodedados");
        echo "<table style='1px'>";
        echo    "<thead>    <tr> <th colspan='6'>Lista 1 </th></tr>";    
        echo "</tread>";
        echo   "<tr>";
        echo "<th> A dado </th> <th> B dado </th> <th> C dado </th>";
        echo " <th>D dado </th> <th> E dado </th> <th> F total </th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo  "</thead>";
        echo   " <tbody>";
    while($linha= mysql_fetch_array($executar)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$linha['A']."</td><td>" .$linha['B'];
        echo  "</td><td>".$linha['C']."</td><td> ".$linha['D'];
        echo "</td><td>  ".$linha['E']."</td><td> ".$linha['F']."</td><br/>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";            
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Alem disso, seu código estava faltando muitos ";"
Como pode ver, as alterações foram:

> $executar = mysql_query("$selecaodedados");
>
> while($linha= mysql_fetch_array($executar)){

Comment: `Desde já eu não recomendo mais utilizar MySql, já que o mesmo é obsoleto e está descontinuado. E também foi removido na versão 7.0.0 do PHP.` - o SGBD mysql foi descontinuado? Tem certeza disso?

Comment: Sim, houve até votação para descontinuar: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation

Comment: Engano seu, o BANCO DE DADOS MYSQL, continua firme, o que foi descontinuado são as funções mysql_ utilizadas dentro do php.

Comment: Mas é isso que estou dizendo? Faltou especificar? ok, eu especifico!

Comment: Por que replicou a pergunta na sua resposta?

Comment: Não tinha visto. Obrigado!

Comment: Grato pela ajuda  irmao, mas por lapso deixei o query de lado no último exemplo, embora já havia tentado, e mesmo o utilizando, os dados nao sao mostrados.

Comment: Como alternativa ao MySql o que devo usar?

Comment: Depois de vários testes percebi que o que nao permitia a visualiçao da informaçao do BD utilizando o mysql_fetch_array no meu caso foi uma tag br esquecida de um recorte anterior. Muito grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Para facilitar vc pode colocar um `for` dentro o `while`:

```
<table>
<?php
    while($linha= mysql_fetch_row($selecaodedados)){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($x=0; $x<count($linha); $x++)
            echo "<td>".$linha[$x]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

Usar o `mysql_fetch_assoc` você terá um vetor numérico para as informações, assim ficará mais fácil percorrer como um vetor.

Comment: Grato irmao. De fato ficou muito mais organizado do que apenas chamar os dados com o mysql_fetch_array. No entanto nao há como conseguir colocar as informaçoes no head da tabela ou mesmo estiliza-la colocando borda ou afins? A ediçao do site retirou a parte em que informei que sou iniciante em programaçao, portanto perdao por qualquer besteira que esteja a dizer.

Comment: @LucasMenezes, ainda é possível fazer o que quiser com a tabela pelo CSS, basta colocar o código CSS normalmente alterando a tabela, para colocar o `head` também, você pode usar um `echo` com o head da tabela, ou colocar fora da tag php.

Comment: Havia tentado, sem sucesso. O resultado que tive fora algo estranho. Tanto com a head dentro do php quanto fora, o que o servidor me retornou foi 39 repetições de  for(=0; escritas em linha, e abaixo as informações da Head. Por isso perguntei se era possível estilizar a tabela gerada pela busca. Mas a pouco percebi onde estava o erro da minha sintaxe. O "for" que me recomendou usar, está sem um par de chaves circulando-o.

Comment: Só mais duas perguntas irmao. Caso nao queira mostrar todas as colunas do BD como recomendaria codificar? E como o outro amigo informou que o Mysql está caindo em desuso, o que você recomenda como boa alternativa?

Comment: O mysql não está em desuso, a função `mysql` está ficando obsoleta no php e estão migrando para o `mysqli`. No caso dos campos, o melhor método seria não selecionar os campos no SQL, ou usar o `mysql_fetch_assoc` e o `foreach` e uma condição para os campos que não desejá mostrar

Comment: Embora o aviso de "evite comentários como Obrigado" acho muito deselegante e de uma frieza muito grande, sair sem agradecer pela ajuda. Grato irmão.